# R: give data frames new names based on contents of their current name

Tags: r, loops, if-statement, dataframe

I'm writing a script to plot data from multiple files. Each file is named using the same format, where  strings between “.” give some info on what is in the file. For example, SITE.TT.AF.000.52.000.001.002.003.WDSD_30.csv.

These data will be from multiple sites, so `SITE`, or `WDSD_30`, or any other string, may be different depending on where the data is from, though it's position in the file name will always indicate a specific feature such as location or measurement.

So far I have each file read into R and saved as a data frame named the same as the file. I'd like to get something like the following to work: if there is a data frame in the global environment that contains `WDSD_30`, then plot a specific column from that data frame. The column will always have the same name, so I could write `plot(WDSD_30$meas)`, and no matter what site's files were loaded in the global environment, the script would find the `WDSD_30` file and plot the `meas` variable. My goal for this script is to be able to point it to any folder containing files from a particular site, and no matter what the site, the script will be able to read in the data and find files containing the variables I'm interested in plotting.

A colleague suggested I try using `strsplit()` to break up the file name and extract the element I want to use, then use that to rename the data frame containing that element. I'm stuck on how exactly to do this or whether this is the best approach.

Here's what I have so far:

```
site.files<- basename(list.files( pattern = ".csv",recursive = TRUE,full.names= FALSE))

sfsplit<- lapply(site.files, function(x) strsplit(x, ".", fixed =T)[[1]])

for (i in 1:length(site.files)) assign(site.files[i],read.csv(site.files[i]))

for (i in 1:length(site.files)) 
if (sfsplit[[i]][10]==grep("PARQL", sfsplit[[i]][10])) 
{assign(data.frame.getting.named.PARQL, sfsplit[[i]][10])}
else if (sfsplit[i][10]==grep("IRBT", sfsplit[[i]][10]))
{assign(data.frame.getting.named.IRBT, sfsplit[[i]][10])
```

...and so on for each data frame I'd like to eventually plot from.Is this a good approach, or is there some better way?  I'm also unclear on how to refer to the objects I made up for this example, `data.frame.getting.named.xxxx`, without using the entire filename as it was read into R. Is there something like `data.frame[1]` to generically refer to the 1st data frame in the global environment.

Comment: You want a `?list` . Run `allfiles <- lapply(site.files, read.csv)` and then you can access `allfiles[[1]]` etc... to get the data from each file.

Comment: This is an excellent suggestion. All the data saved to a list of lists, each dataset referenced as a member of that list. Thanks for that! Do you know if `lapply()` will always work such that `site.files[1]` is the dataset creating `allfiles[[1]]`? I'm wondering if I can loop through `site.files` to extract names of each dataset, then use that list for something like `name[1] =allfiles[[1]]`. I can see this being problematic if for some reason `lapply()` doesn't always proceed sequentially. I could end up with datasets named after measurements from other datasets. Thanks again @thelatemail!

Comment: lapply is always sequential, but you could always call the result like allfiles["filename"] too if you have the need.